# Django admin - Use inlines in django admin saving data in current model

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, inline

I need use inlines in django admin for show relation between two models but in the moment that i do, i had to do the reverse relationship to show inlines.

Example:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
  field1=models...
  ........

class Model(models.Model)
  field1 = models....
  other_model = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)
```

I create the inline...

```
class OtherModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = OtherModel
  extra = 1

@admin.register(Model):
class ModelAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
  inlines = [OtherModelInline]
```

So... 
When I create the Inline it required foreign key on OtherModel.. 
How can I show this without change the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it.

If you want to use inlines, you need to specify that these two models are somewhat related.